# Migrating from rosbuild to catkin: <export> <cpp> </export> equivalent

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,
I'm working on switching beetween rosbuild & catkin build system. In my old rosbuild package **manifest.xml**, there is this macro:

which I don't know how to transfer to catkin. Some suggestions say that it must be done in **CMakeLists.txt** `catkin_package()`  but there are no options for cflags and/or lflags.

Any help will be appreciated

Thank you,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/204743/migrating-from-rosbuild-to-catkin:-%3Cexport%3E-%3Ccpp%3E-%3C/export%3E-equivalent/) by [Huy Cong](https://answers.ros.org/users/21813/huy-cong/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2015-03-11

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

catkin_package is correct, see
http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/CMakeLists.txt#catkin_package.28.29

INCLUDE_DIRS take the role of cflags and LIBRARIES are like lflags, just that in both cases you don't specify explicit flags, but links the exported include directories and libraries to link.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2015-03-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-03-11**:
Just to add to this: if you need to export actual `C(XX)_FLAGS` (so not just include paths), that should be done using the `CFG_EXTRAS` argument to `catkin_package(..)`.

**Comment by [Huy Cong](https://answers.ros.org/users/21813/huy-cong/) on 2015-03-11**:
Yes thats exactly what I want to do. My flags to export is **-std=c++0x**. The `CFG_EXTRAS` is quite difficult to understand, so I have to create a .cmake file that has   `set (C(XX)_FLAGS ...)`  then export the whole script?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-03-11**:
Yes. You create a `your_pkg-extras.cmake` in a `cmake/` subdir, then add the `CFG_EXTRAS` to your `catkin_package(..)` line. For setting `CXX_FLAGS` I'd use `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++0x")`, as you want to append, not overwrite.

**Comment by [Huy Cong](https://answers.ros.org/users/21813/huy-cong/) on 2015-03-11**:
I tried   `catkin_package(.. CFG_EXTRAS {my_cmake}.cmake.develspace.in)`   but   `{my_cmake}`  file was not build into   `devel/{my_package}/cmake/{my_package}`  directory, what has gone wrong? should I replace the name of the cmake file?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-03-11**:
Adding a single option to the `CXX_FLAGS` does not really require using a templated extras file. Just make it a regular `-extras.cmake`, without the `.develspace.in`. Also: as far as I know, the extras file doesn't end up in `devel`. Only in `install`.

**Comment by [Huy Cong](https://answers.ros.org/users/21813/huy-cong/) on 2015-03-11**:
Its ok to use  `-extras.cmake` , but I want my file to end up in  `devel` , so other package can see and include it also, is there a way to do it?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-03-11**:\

> so other package can see and include it also

You don't need to include it in other pkgs. `catkin` takes care of that. It's all auto-magic.